# My jsx file doesn´t recognize the <strong> attribute?

Tags: reactjs

Im working in React JS and it seems that the jsx file doesnt recognize the  att. Is that possible? Here is my code:

```
<div className="LoginFormContainer">
        <h1>
          Welcome to <strong> {APP_TITLE} </strong>
        </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you importing react? `import React from 'react';`

Comment: What does it say when you run this code ?

Comment: no errors in cosole. Just doesnt´t looks like "strong"

Comment: Please post the whole file where the error appears